# WordPress Twilio Inbound SMS Callback URL failing when request method is POST

Tags: wordpress, sms, civisms, twilio

I set up Twilio with CiviCRM and WordPress a few weeks ago. Inbound SMS was working fine, but suddenly stopped.

I have the webhook URL for SMS in Twilio set to https://mydomain.com/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fsms%2Fcallback&provider=org.civicrm.sms.twilio (the /civicrm/ is for the Page I have setup, before adding that it would only work when I was logged into WordPress).

When the webhook is set to use HTTP POST, Twilio is reporting a "Schema validation warning" because it's just getting WordPress HTML back for the website home page. It works when I set it to GET though. I've reproduced this behaviour via a PHP script that manually submits the POST/GET request.

How can I get this Twilio Provider extension to respond via WordPress to a POST request? What am I missing? 
(This seems similar to [Inbound SMS from Twilio not showing up in CiviCRM (getting 404 error on HTTP POST)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16746/inbound-sms-from-twilio-not-showing-up-in-civicrm-getting-404-error-on-http-pos#comment18669_16749) but I'm new here and don't have the reputation to comment.)

Or does it matter? The documentation says it should be set up to use POST, but maybe that's not important?

Answer (score 1):

Your webhook callback URL is off.
It should be `https://mydomain.com/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fsms%2Fcallback&provider=org.civicrm.sms.twilio`