# Not receiving Telerivet SMS to CiviCRM

Tags: sms

I've followed all the [instructions according to this documentation](https://github.com/nditech/org.ndi.sms.telerivet) but when I test the incoming SMS', I do not see the SMS's coming into CiviCRM.

Below are the settings I have set up in Telerivet and then copied to Civi

[image: These are the API keys]

This is the Webhook settings
[image: This is the Webhook]

And here I would expect to see the option to send an SMS

[image]

I also would like to see where the incoming SMS would come into. According to the video, a report can be set up to show all the incoming SMS's but I cannot seem to create the same report.

Answer (score 2):

For sending sms, the contact should have Phone number of phone type as '**Mobile**' and Primary as true. The option will be visible once you set required phone type.

The incoming message will be shown under Activity tab of Contact of Activity type as **Inbound SMS**. You can also check using Activity search with filter Activity type as **Inbound SMS**. You can also create Activity report with with filter Activity type as **Inbound SMS** and have it available on dashboard.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Adding the number as an Mobile number worked however, I still cannot send or receive the SMS's. Could this be due to the account being in Test Plan mode?

Comment: Did you got any error?

Comment: And are the relevant cron jobs enabled?

Comment: @JaapJansma - no cron jobs are necessary for the SMS workflows outlined above. They are only needed for sending scheduled mass SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Pradeep has covered a couple of the issues already, but for the sake of completeness:

> here I would expect to see the option to send an SMS

Ensure that the contact has a phone of type 'mobile'

> I also would like to see where the incoming SMS would come into

An Activity report filtered by activity type Incoming SMS should do the trick

> This is the Webhook settings
>   https://crm.helderberghospice.org.za/civicrm/sms/callback

I tested that URL and it came back with "Page not found". It looks like you are using Wordpress, in which case the form of callback URL is different. Based on [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22083/wordpress-twilio-inbound-sms-callback-url-failing-when-request-method-is-post/22090) and your existing callback, I suspect that your webhook should be:

https://crm.helderberghospice.org.za/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fsms%2Fcallback&provider=org.ndi.sms.telerivet

Comment: Thanks Michael. Got sidetracked and back on this problem now

Comment: Hi Michael, I made a comment in the repo too but I seem to be having problems with the URL. Could you please see this for me?

https://github.com/nditech/org.ndi.sms.telerivet/issues/1